# pyautogui Не зажимается левая кнопка мыши в игре

Tags: python, mouse-event, pyautogui

**Дано**: Игра в оконном режиме, OS: Windows 10 x64

**Задача**: Написать код на Python 3.7+

1. Перетащить указатель мыши на определённую позицию    <--- Работает
2. **Зажать левую кнопку мыши                     <--- Не работает**
3. Переместить указатель мыши на определённую позицию   <--- Работает
4. Отпустить левую кнопку мыши                  <--- Работает

**Что было сделано**:

```
import pyautogui
import time

# pyautogui.dragTo и pyautogui.drag не работают.

pyautogui.moveTo(777, 777)
time.sleep(0.5)
pyautogui.mouseDown(button='left')
time.sleep(0.5)
pyautogui.moveTo(555, 555)
time.sleep(0.5)
pyautogui.mouseUp(button='left')
```

**Результат**: Указатель мыши перемещается на заданную точку, кнопка мыши не зажимается.

**Библиотеки которые я использовал для решения этой проблемы, но они не сработали**:

1. win32api.mouse_event
2. pydirectinput
3. pywinauto

Нажатие клавиш, перемещение мыши, клики мыши работают отлично.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кнопка зажимается... Всё дело в том что игра отменяет все нажатия если мышка не естественно перемещается.